# convert negative unixtimestamp to normal datetime

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

There is a problem when using Mysql to extract data: negative timestamp cannot pass `FROM_ UNIXTIME` method converted to normal date:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(-2641363543)

Null
```

I know the correct date corresponding to this timestamp is: 1886-04-20 00:00:00. I searched for it, and some people suggested that can be calculated in a relative way:

```
DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), INTERVAL -2641363543 SECOND)

1886-04-19 23:54:17
```

But there is a few minutes gap between the calculated period and the correct value. I don't know what the problem is and what the correct method should be.

Comment: -2641363543 is 1886-04-19 15:54:17 UTC according to Perl `print scalar gmtime(-2641363543)` and Ruby `Time.at(-2641363543).utc`. `1886-04-20 00:00:00 UTC` is -2641334400. `Time.gm(1886, 4, 20).to_i`

Comment: So why they are different?

Comment: MySQL is returning in your time zone. `set time_zone = '+00:00'` to get consistent results. How did you calculate -2641363543 to be 1886-04-20 00:00:00? ***And in what time zone***?

Comment: One possibility is that -2641363543 corresponds to astronomical midnight in some particular city. Time zones weren't a thing in 1886 so some time libraries will provide local time using an offset based on the longitude of the city.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear just from looking at it that -2641363543 is not midnight. If subtracted from `1970-01-01 00:00:00` it would need to end with a zero.

According to both Ruby and Perl it is 1886-04-19 15:54:17 UTC.

```
> Time.at(-2641363543).utc 
 => 1886-04-19 15:54:17 UTC
```

You want `-2641334400`.

```
> Time.gm(1886, 4, 20).to_i
 => -2641334400
```

And the technique does work.

```
mysql> set time_zone = '+00:00';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME(0) + INTERVAL -2641334400 SECOND;
+------------------------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(0) + INTERVAL -2641334400 SECOND |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 1886-04-20 00:00:00                            |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Which brings us to perhaps the real problem...

> the correct date corresponding to this timestamp is: 1886-04-20 00:00:00

Correct ***for which time zone***?